# How to write conditional statement that does something only if xcopy copies something (exit code 0)

Tags: batch-file, if-statement, xcopy, errorlevel

I would like to create a conditional statement for xcopy that does something only if xcopy copies something.

So basically what I am saying is, if xcopy copies a file, do something.

If not do something else.

How this be done using a batch?

So far I have the following:

```
xcopy "Z:\TestFiles.zip" "C:\Test\" /d /y

if xcopy exit code 0 (

)else
```

**UPDATE:**

**When running the following script:**

```
xcopy /d /y "Z:\TestFiles.zip" "C:\Testing\"

echo %errorlevel%
```

**The following are the results I get:**

> 1 File(s) copied
>
> C:\Users\jmills\Desktop>echo 0
>
> 0

_

> 0
>   File(s) copied
>
> C:\Users\jmills\Desktop>echo 0
>
> 0

**Because both error codes come out to 0 I cannot use:**

```
IF ERRORLEVEL 1 GOTO FilesCopied
IF ERRORLEVEL 0 GOTO NoFiledCopied

:NoFiledCopied
REM do something
GOTO eof

:FilesCopied
REM  do something
GOTO eof

:eof
```

Comment: I think the variable you are looking for is `%errorlevel%`.

Comment: Yes, but I just learned I cannot rely on %errorlevel% for xcopy on windows 10. As it will always show 0

Comment: Please reread all these links again. [Tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour). Please read, [How to ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Also please read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: I just tested `XCOPY` on Windows 10 and when the file does not exist the errorlevel is set to `4`.  Sure would like to see how you are getting a `0`.

Comment: Were you to use `RoboCopy` which superseded `XCopy` way back in the previous decade, you could utilise it's [error codes](https://ss64.com/nt/robocopy-exit.html).

Comment: `xcopy /D /Y "Z:\TestFiles.zip" "C:\Test\"`[`&&`](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-redirection.html)`echo success.`[`||`](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-redirection.html)`echo Failure!`?

Comment: @aschipfl  Thank you. I used that same principal in my code. Iwill mark that as the answer if you post it, also can you please take a look at my newest post? I still need help with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the [conditional execution operators `&&` and `||`](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-redirection.html):

```cmd
xcopy /D /Y "Z:\TestFiles.zip" "C:\Test\" && echo success. || echo Failure!
```

---

Alternatively, you could check the [`ErrorLevel`](http://ss64.com/nt/errorlevel.html) value:

```cmd
xcopy /D /Y "Z:\TestFiles.zip" "C:\Test\"
rem // The following consition means 'if ErrorLevel is greater than or equal to 1':
if ErrorLevel 1 (
    echo Failure!
) else (
    echo Success.
)
```

This works because [`xcopy`](http://ss64.com/nt/xcopy.html) does not return a negative `ErrorLevel` value.

---

Or you could query the value of the `%ErrorLevel%` pseudo-[variable](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-variables.html):

```cmd
xcopy /D /Y "Z:\TestFiles.zip" "C:\Test\"
if %ErrorLevel% equ 0 (
    echo Success.
) else (
    echo Failure!
)
```

Note that if the above code is placed within a (parenthesised) block of code, you need to enable and apply [delayed variable expansion](http://ss64.com/nt/delayedexpansion.html) to get the latest `!ErrorLevel!` value.

---

According to your [update](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/55249381/3), you want to detect whether or not `xcopy` copied any files. As per this related [Super User thread](https://superuser.com/q/1180180), `xcopy` never returns an exit code of `1` (which I consider a design flaw), contrary to the [documentation](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc771254%28v=ws.11%29.aspx), even if the `/D` option is used and no files are copied.

To circumvent this you could capture the returned summary message (`# File(s)`) by a [`for /F` loop](http://ss64.com/nt/for_f.html), extract the number (`#`) and check whether it is greater than `0`. The exit code should still be checked though as there might occur other exceptions:

```cmd
rem // Initialise variable:
set "NUM=0"
rem /* Use a `for /F` loop to capture the output of `xcopy` line by line;
rem    the first token is stored in a variable, which is overwritten in
rem    each loop iteration, so it finally holds the last token, which is
ewm    nothing but the number of copied files; if `xcopy` fails, number `0`
rem    is echoed, which is then captured as well: */
for /F "tokens=1" %%E in ('
    2^> nul xcopy /D /Y "Z:\TestFiles.zip" "C:\Test\" ^|^| echo 0
') do (
    rem // Capture first token of a captured line:
    set "NUM=%%E"
)
rem // Compare the finally retrieved count of copied files:
if %NUM% gtr 0 (
    echo Success.
) else (
    echo Failure!
)
```

Regard that the captured summary line is language-dependent, so the token to extract, as well as the echoed failure text (`0`), might need to be adapted accordingly.

Comment: I actually found that xcopy always gives errorlevel 0 even whether files are copied or not.

Comment: [`xcopy`](http://ss64.com/nt/xcopy.html)'s exit code is reliable; what did you try (perhaps [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/55249381/edit) your question and add your attempts)...

Answer (score 0):

You could use `robocopy` instead of `xcopy`:

```
ROBOCOPY "Z:\\" "C:\Test\\" "TestFiles.zip"
IF ERRORLEVEL 1 GOTO FilesCopied
IF ERRORLEVEL 0 GOTO NoFiledCopied

:NoFiledCopied
REM do something
GOTO eof

:FilesCopied
REM  do something
GOTO eof

:eof
```

Further information about `robocopy`:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/robocopy

Comment: @Squashman : Please verify that your modified version still works when editing working code, but thx for improving the coding style. (A trailing backslash for source or destination in quotes is treated as an escape character.)

Comment: I keep receiving error code 3 meaning there are some files being copied, but all files in both directories are the same. Why does it give me this error. I am currently using your format

Comment: @Gmork, yep forgot about that with Robocopy. My best practice is still to use quotes so you could write it as: `ROBOCOPY "Z:" "C:\Test" "TestFiles.zip"`